# yaml - static website - configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, static, web

i've got a website hostet on google app engine:

app.yaml:

```
application: ****
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /style\.css
  static_files: style.css
  upload: style\.css

- url: /script-min\.js
  static_files: script-min.js
  upload: script-min\.js

- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.html)

- url: /browserconfig\.xml
  static_files: browserconfig.xml
  upload: browserconfig\.xml)

- url: /(.*\.(jpg|png|svg))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(jpg|png|svg)

- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index\.html


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

my folder structure is very easy: all files in root dir except images which are in a folder called images

however I'm gettin followin error when trying to deploy:

```
ERROR    2014-11-16 21:45:17,131 http_runtime.py:285] bad runtime process port ['']
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 83, in <module>

    _run_file(__file__, globals())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 79, in _run_file

    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 176, in <module>

    main()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 154, in main

    sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 173, in enable_sandbox

    stubs.FakeFile.set_static_files(config.static_files)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py", line 193, in set_static_files

    FakeFile._static_files = re.compile(static_files)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile

    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 245, in _compile

    raise error, v # invalid expression

sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

thx for helping me out...

Comment: just delete each section in turn until it works, then you've found the section with the problem. Also I don't think you need to escape the dots in the URL.

Comment: A failure to interpret "unbalanced parenthesis" is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error:

**sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis**

and lo!

```
upload: (.*\.(jpg|png|svg)
```

Comment: also this one: upload: browserconfig\.xml)